# How to inhibit Term::ReadLine's default filename completion?

Tags: perl, tab-completion

How can I disable [`Term::ReadLine`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine)'s default completion, or rather, make it stop suggesting filename completions at some point?

For example, what do I need to replace `return()` with in order to inhibit the default completion from the second word onwards?

Neither of these works:

```perl
    $attribs->{'filename_completion_function'}=undef;
    $attribs->{'rl_inhibit_completion'}=1;
```

```perl
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term    = new Term::ReadLine 'sample';
my $attribs = $term->Attribs;
$attribs->{attempted_completion_function} = \&sample_completion;

sub sample_completion {
    my ( $text, $line, $start, $end ) = @_;

    # If first word then username completion, else filename completion
    if ( substr( $line, 0, $start ) =~ /^\s*$/ ) {

        return $term->completion_matches( $text,
            $attribs->{'username_completion_function'} );
    }
    else {
        return ();
    }
}

while ( my $input = $term->readline( "> " ) ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Try `filename_completion_desired`

Comment: Like this: `$attribs->{filename_completion_desired}=0;`? Or maybe `$attribs->{rl_filename_completion_desired}=0;`? Not working.

Comment: I'm just guessing from the docs. All the variable names are documented [**here**](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu#Term::ReadLine::Gnu-Variables) for the Gnu variant. The keys to the `$attribs` hash have the leading `rl_` removed. You may have to `use Term::ReadLine::Gnu` or set the environment variable `PERL_RL` to `Gnu` for those to work.

Comment: Thanks. We are not allowed to `use Term::ReadLine::Gnu` directly. By trial and error, it seems the way to go is to define, not `attempted_completion_function`, but `completion_function`, and then `return $term->completion_matches($text, $attribs->{filename_completion_function})` whenever the default filename completion is to take over.

Comment: Well done. You should write that up as an answer and accept it. All this bureaucracy that prohibits people from using modules is bizarre!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `completion_function` instead of `attempted_completion_function`:

```perl
$attribs->{completion_function} = \&completion;
```

And then `return undef` if completion should stop, and `return $term->completion_matches($text, $attribs->{filename_completion_function})` if filename completion is to take over.

In the following example, nothing is suggested for the first parameter, but filenames are for the second parameter.

```perl
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term = new Term::ReadLine 'sample';
my $attribs = $term->Attribs;
$attribs->{completion_function} = \&completion;

sub completion {

  my ( $text, $line, $start ) = @_;

  if ( substr( $line, 0, $start ) =~ /^\s*$/) {

    return 

  } else {

    return $term->completion_matches($text, $attribs->{filename_completion_function})

  }
}

while ( my $input = $term->readline ("> ") ) {
  exit 0 if $input eq "q";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the Gnu implementation I discovered that I can set `attempted_completion_over` to avoid filename completions when my `attempted_completion_function` returns no results:

```
$attribs->{attempted_completion_over} = 1;
```

[Gnu.pm](https://metacpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Gnu/source/Gnu.pm#L668) indicates this variable is as of "GRL 4.2".

Note that you should set this variable *every time* your `attempted_completion_function` runs, or at least every time it returns no matches.  I don't see that documented anywhere, but libreadline apparently [resets the variable to zero](https://github.com/kobolabs/readline/blob/d49a9082c0e15bba8cd3d8cc0a994409cf823cac/complete.c#L1242) after every call.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in my completion handler:

```
if <no more matches> then
    $attribs->{completion_entry_function} = \&dummy;
```

i.e.:

```
sub complete {
    my $text = shift // '';
    my $line = shift // '';
    my $start = shift // 0;
    my $end = shift // 0;
    # msg("$text, $line, $start, $end");
    my @matches = $g->complete($text, $line, $start, $end);
    # msg(vDump(\@matches));
    $attribs->{completion_entry_function} = \&dummy;
    return @matches;
}
$attribs->{attempted_completion_function} = \&complete;
```